# Проблема при отрисовке plot(kind = 'scatter') и boxplot() для бинарного признака на одном графике

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я хочу отрисовать `scatterplot` и `boxplot` на одном графике.

В моей таблице есть столбец `yr` (признак-год - принимает значения 0 и 1) и столбец `cnt` (это данные про прокат велосипедов, количество арендуемых велосипедов).

Если я пишу следующий код:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))
df.plot('yr', "cnt", kind="scatter", ax = ax)
```

То `scatterplot` отображается нормально - получается два облака точек над 0 и над 1. Однако, если добавить еще строчку с `boxplot`, то почему-то все точки `scatterplot` отображаются над значением 0.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))
df.plot('yr', "cnt", kind="scatter", ax = ax)
df.boxplot(column = 'cnt', by = 'yr', ax = ax)
```

Аналогичный код для столбца, в котором содержится признак с четырьмя значениями отображается нормально - облака точек не собираются над одним значением, а располагаются над соответствующими отметками по оси x. Еще есть различие - в случае, когда только `scatterplot` отображается - у меня на графике сетка
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
а когда вместе с `boxplot` - то только два значения 0 и 1 - может тут в типах дело?

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как можно отрисовать, чтобы `scatterplot` не смещался в одну точку при отрисовке `boxplot`?

Вот так это выглядит:

[image: Все точки сместились в ноль]

Comment: Вы можете привести пример данных? Например запостить вывод: `print(df.head(10))`

Comment: Я справился с проблемой, но не понимаю как. Ниже приведу решение в своем ответе. Не знаю как тут красиво показать данные - поэтому просто расскажу. Это dataframe, В ней есть столбцы

Index([u'season', u'yr', u'mnth', u'holiday', u'weekday', u'workingday',
       u'weathersit', u'temp', u'atemp', u'hum', u'windspeed(mph)',
       u'windspeed(ms)', u'cnt'], dtype='object')

В столбце год есть только два значения - 0 и 1. В столбце cnt - количество арендуемых велосипедов. Моя задача - вывести все значения cnt с разбивкой по году в виде scatter plot и на том же графике - ящики с усами.

Comment: Вот ссылка на данные

https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_1fbbe0f3404552777e1932b2a209e803_bikes_rent.csv?Expires=1501718400&Signature=B3yqiJOgLLCeHSUHA8oIdsm6EI7c0lXzAC9zrLs~X5FYDU03uN80bdLUdP-6mQ2jPryOm-3xOSSB8GaTPNR2KDTpJKmrGxeRMTyQb0UtFdCuUxyFXoSs2aj9HK69NasAidri5QqwqKmLIUC~xaBR1SclJjV4PhmkbJXvXEE9stA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Answer (score 2):

После длительных метаний я таки открыл ответ. Но сам не очень понимаю, почему это решило проблему (ведь я что-то изменил в параметрах функции boxplot, а изменилась отрисовка scatterplot - для меня это какая-то мистика, может кто-то пояснит).

Итак - решение оказалось таким (я просто закинул пару [0, 1] в параметр positions функции boxplot и все стало как надо):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 4))

pos = np.array([0, 1])
df.boxplot(column = 'cnt', by='yr', positions = pos, ax=ax)
df.plot('yr', 'cnt', kind='scatter', ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

Теперь все рисует так, как я и хотел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/)

Пример данных:

```
In [322]: df = pd.DataFrame({'yr':np.random.choice([0,1], 100, p=[.4,.6]), 
                             'cnt':np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)})

In [323]: df
Out[323]:
    cnt  yr
0    86   0
1    50   1
2    96   1
3    48   1
4    61   0
5    70   1
6     8   1
7     9   0
8    25   0
9    81   1
..  ...  ..
90   18   1
91   61   1
92    2   1
93   52   0
94   74   0
95   29   0
96   37   1
97   39   1
98   23   0
99   99   0

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Графики:

```
In [324]: import seaborn as sns

In [325]: sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

In [326]: sns.violinplot(data=df, x='yr', y='cnt', color_codes=True, style='whitegrid')
Out[326]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x133a8a58>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]